# DialogFlow confuses time and number

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I want to define an intent `PlaceReservation` that would capture a restaurant reservation. The parameters for that would be `numOfPeople` and `time`. Both of those parameters are optional, so a user can say:

- get a table for 5 people for 9pm
- get a table for 5 people
- get a table for 9pm
- get a table
- get a table for 5
- get a table for 9pm for 5 people
- get a table for 5 for 9pm

My problem is with the last one, `get a table for 5 for 9pm` the intent then captures 5 as the hour (5am) and ignores 9pm.
`time` is defined as a `@sys.time` system entity.

Is there a way to tell it to not accept simple integers as time, as I think this is what is confusing it?

Is there some other solution I'm missing?
I certainly understand why it is making the mistake, but we, as humans understand how to interpret it, and I want to help DialogFlow interpret it accordingly.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the Intent's sample phrases you're using and the parameters that are matching it?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem and haven't found a proper solution for it yet. In your case you could define your own time entity that consists of entries like 9pm or 10am or even expand it with a composite entity to also let users say "10 in the morning" https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities#dev_composite.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely confusing for the bot to understand/interpret which one is time & which one is the number of people. Even creating a separate entity for `time` like `9am/10am` won't work cause this does not guarantee that user will enter `9am/pm` only. They may not append `am/pm` ahead of time as well. The solution to your problem can be creating separate intents, first asking users for time & then for number of people. This way you reduce the complexity & can train the bot in a proper way. In addition, you can direct user to a certain direction instead of keeping your bot open for questions.